# Capybara::ElementNotFound radio by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I understand the syntax for Capybara choosing a radio button is the following

```
choose("Label Name")
```

I am running into an issue with doing this for a label that has its default name changed to an `#id`.

Here is my HTML

```
 <label for="school_application_I_20"> Do you require an I-20 Form?</label>
    <br>
    <label for="school_application_I_20_true">Yes</label>
    <input id="i-20-1" name="school_application[I_20]" type="radio" value="true" />
    <label for="school_application_I_20_false">No</label>
    <input id="i-20-2" name="school_application[I_20]" type="radio" value="false" />
    <br>
```

When I try to do the old method of choosing the element with

```
 choose('school_application_I_20_true')
```

I get

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find radio button "school_application_I_20_true"
```

When I change the choose to use the element ID I get the same error but for the ID. Is there a way to select a radio button by ID?

Comment: Why don't the "for" attributes match the ids of the radios? That will prevent being able to click on the label to toggle the radio selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping a label and trying to treat it as a radio? perhaps map the input which has type=radio, most likely then you will be able to use choose method for that element:

```
choose("i-20-1")
```

not sure if you really need the # prior to the id for choose method... if it doesnt find the element successfully try:

```
choose("#i-20-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first and default functionality of the `choose()` takes in an `#id`.

But one does not specify the `#` character.